# Double integration of discrete data with respect to time

Tags: python, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

Let's say I have a set of data points called `signal` and I want to integrate it twice with respect to time (i.e., if `signal` was acceleration, I'd like to integrate it twice w.r.t. time to get the position). I can integrate it once using `simps` but the output here is a scalar. How can you numerically integrate a (random) data set twice? I'd imagine it would look something like this, but obviously the inputs are not compatible after the first integration.

```
n_samples = 5000
t_range = np.arange(float(n_samples))
signal = np.random.normal(0.,1.,n_samples)
signal_integration = simps(signal, t_range)
signal_integration_double = simps(simps(signal, t_range), t_range)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I answered too fast. `scipy.integrate.simps` give the value of the integration over the range you give it, similar to `np.sum(signal)`.

What you want is the integration beween the start and each data point, which is what `cumsum` does. A better method could be `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz`. You can apply either method twice to get the result you want.

See:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html

**Original answer:**
I think you want `np.cumsum`. Integration of discrete data is just a sum. You have to multiply the result by the step value to get the correct scale.

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `np.sum(signal)*dt` for a single integration and presumably `np.sum(signal)*dt**2` for a double integration? Why use `np.cumsum`?

Comment: The formula for integration would be something like `signal_integration = [sum(signal[:i]) for i in range(n_samples)]`. That is what `cumsum` computes, but more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

By partial integration you get from `y''=f` to

```
y(t) = y(0) + y'(0)*t + integral from 0 to t of (t-s)*f(s) ds
```

As you seem to assume that `y(0)=0` and also `y'(0)=0`, you can thus get the the desired integral value in one integration as

```
simps((t-t_range)*signal, t_range)
```